# Oracle: Incorrect language compiled in PLSQL from sqlplus

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, nls, nls-lang

I have some danish names in my plsql proc. Whenever i try to compile from TOAD, the danish words get compile in correctly in my database.
But whenever i try to com pile from sqlplus, the danish special characters gets scrammbled and

eg Ø comes as Ã,Æ comes as Ã|

My nls_language parameter in datasbase and for both toad and sqlplus sessions are AMERICAN. CHaracterset in database is UTF8, i didnt find charactrer for sessions. I have changed the NLS_LANGUAGE parameter to DANISH by altering session but of no use.

Can anyone help on to figure out the solution on this so that i can compile my code properly from sqlplus which has non-english characters.

Comment: Hi, If there are only some chars(less than 20 maybe) then it is better to use chr(number) instead of typing the character, which is safe, but if you want to have a lot of texts in your program then why don't you use tables instead?

Comment: In my experience it is not safe to put non-English chars in stored programs

Comment: Hello,I am using the names of developers in comments part. i.e -- ThØger just in plsql code as comment and not in any tables.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Germany. I got it working by exporting the script from Toad with Encoding UTF8(no-BOM) and then setting (in the CMD.exe Window)  set NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8

Comment: I have made the encoding of files as ANSI and executed  through SQLplus and this worked. !!